# How Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") is working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-membership

I was trying to hide and show menu bar based on logged in user role. So i've written a code in razor view which is

```
   @if ( Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole( "Admin" ) ) {
                 <li>Projects link</li>
                 <li>Profile link</li>
            }
```

and also this

```
 @if (Roles.IsUserInRole( "Admin" ) ) {
                 <li>Projects link</li>
                 <li>Profile link</li>
            }
```

I have tried both codes, it works but problem is Its not working for all admins. Its working for only one admin when totally 4 user have admin role.

And also same kind when i declaring another user role finance admin its working for a single user!

All other user its blocking the menu but the user roles is same for four users. I dont know how it getting only one user as admin when remaining three also same role.
Can any one explain where the method getting roles from data base and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

The IsInRole method (and all other methods) are stored procedures in your database. In your database, you have the MemberShip tables. The Stored Procedures work on those tables. If you say that the code will work for one user that has the Admin role connected, the first thing I would check is if the other users where it won't work will really have that role. Check the table for all the user and role connections in your database.

Comment: S locktar i've checked! And one more thing i was using asp.net_users table, asp.net_userinroles table and asp.net_roles table to have the user role details! four person having same userid and that userid belongs to admin role! i dont know how it work for one user and not for other users

Comment: Dear Anto, You say that four persons has the same userId? That is not possible. That should not be the way how it works. You have multiple tables. You have a Users, Membership, UserInRole en Roles table. The user with name "example" should have a record in membership and in user. Those tables are coupled by their unique GUID. You have also a record for the Role "Admin" in the Roles table. The unique guid of the users and membership table is used to connect to the role guid. This is done in the userinrole table. If you make a new user ("example2"),that guid is also place in the userinrole table

Comment: So for one user. You have two records in tow different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `webpages_UsersInRoles` table in your database, as this is what governs which roles are attached to which user profiles.

Perhaps there is also an issue with roles being assigned when a user is created. Check your register method on the account controller. You should have a line like this:

`Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, model.userRole);`

If not then roles may not be assigned when a user is created.

Comment: No i dont have a registry method i have assigned all roles in DATABASE itself. and also in my database all the roles are assigned correctly. I'm using ASPNET.Userroles, aspnet.user,asp.net_userinroles tables for this purposes.

Comment: In response to the information you provided to LockTar's answer, you should probably use the UserId as the unique key for the user profile table in your database. Having four users share the same ID is probably causing an issue somewhere.